# Making tagsoup markup cleansing optional

Tags: orbeon

Tagsoup is interfering with input and formatting it incorrectly. For instance when we have the following markup

`<a href="www.google.com"></a>Text outside anchor`

It is formatted as follows

`<a href="www.google.com">Text outside anchor</a>`

This is a simple example but we have other issues as well. So we made tagsoup cleanup/formatting optional by adding an extra attribute to textarea control.

Here is the diff(https://github.com/binnyg/orbeon-forms/commit/044c29e32ce36e5b391abfc782ee44f0354bddd3).

Textarea would now look like this

`<textarea skip-cleanmarkup="true" mediatype="text/html" />`

Two questions

1. Is this the right approach?
2. If I provide a patch can it make it to orbeon codebase?

Thanks
BinnyG

Answer (score 0):

Erik, Alex, et al

I think there are two questions here:

The first Concern is a question of Tag Soup and the clean up that happens OOTB: Empty tags are converted to singleton tags which when consumed/sent to the client browser as markup gets "fixed" by browsers like firefox but because of the loss of precision they do the wrong thing.

Turning off this clean up helps in this case but for this issue alone is not really the right answer because we it takes away a security feature and a well-formed markup feature... so there may need to be some adjustment to the handling of at least certain empty tags (other than turning them in to invalid singleton tags.)

All this brings us to the second concern which is do we always want those features in play?  Our use-case says no.  We want the user to be able to spit out whatever markup they want, invalid or not.  We're not putting the form in an app that needs to protect the user from cross script coding, we're building a tool that lets users edit web pages -- hence we have turned off the clean-up.

But turning off cleanup wholesale?  Well it's important that we can do it if that's what our usecase calls for but the implementation we have is all or nothing.  It would be nice to be able to define strategies for cleanup.  Make that function plug-able.  For example:
* In the XML Config of the system define a "map" of config names to class names which implement the a given strategy. In the XForm Def the author would specify the name from the map.

Answer (score 0):

If TagSoup transforms:

```
<a href="www.google.com"></a>Text outside anchor
```

Into:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Text outside anchor</a>
```

Wouldn't that be bug in TagSoup? If that was the case, then I'd say that it is better to fix this issue rather than disable TagSoup. But, it isn't a bug in TagSoup; here is what seems to be happening. Say the browsers sends the following to the client:

```
<a shape="rect"></a>After<br clear="none">
```

This goes through TagSoup, the result goes through the XSLT clean-up code, and the following is sent to the browser:

```
<a shape="rect"/>After<br clear="none"/>
```

The issue is on the browser, which transforms this into:

```
<a shape="rect">After</a><br clear="none"/>
```

The problem is that we serialize this as XML with `Dom4jUtils.domToString(cleanedDocument)`, while it would be more prudent to serialize it as HTML. Here we could use the Saxon serializer. It is also used from `HTMLSerializer`. Maybe you can try changing this code to use it instead of using `Dom4jUtils.domToString()`. You'll let us know what you find when a get a chance to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Binesh and I agree, if there is a bug it would be a good idea to address the issue closer to the root.  But I think the specific issue he is only part of the matter.

We're thinking it would be best to have some kind of name-to-strategy mapping so that RTEs can call in the server-side processing that is right for them or the default if it's not specified.

Comment: In our case we trust the users and the content. No cleanup is necessary. To Russ's point it would be better if clean up strategy is  plug-gable or completely disabled.

Comment: Would a configuration parameter be good enough for the use cases you have in mind? With this, you would be able to set disable the clean-up for your whole application, or just on a form-per-form basis.

Comment: It would be better if we can do it form-per-form basis but a global configuration parameter would suffice for the current use case.

Comment: Right, and with a configuration parameter, as you know, you get both: you can define a default global value in your `properties-local.xml`, and you can override it for each form by adding an attribute on your form's model. For instance, to override `oxf.xforms.xpath-analysis`, you add the attribute `xxforms:xpath-analysis="true"`.